# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_X_Y' on table 'X' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, cascade

So while publishing my database scripts in Visual Studio, I get this exact error: **Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Users_Manager' on table 'Users' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.**

This is my simplified script for creating a self referencing Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ManagerId] INT NULL,
    [Data] NVARCHAR(1024) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users_UserID] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Manager] FOREIGN KEY ([ManagerId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserId]) ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

Even if somehow I made a cycle on these relationships, I don't see why wouldn't deleted row's **direct** children have their ManagerId set to `NULL`?

Should I create a trigger for this scenario to set `NULL`s for me instead? Or is there something I am clearly missing?

Comment: Please, check this other post: [Cycles or multiple cascade paths with on delete set null: really?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206585/cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-with-on-delete-set-null-really)

Comment: I see, one of the answers is also suggesting a workaround by using a trigger. I'm new to SQL Server and it seems very strange to me that there is no for each row trigger, would have made my life so much easier!

Comment: You can replicate a "for each row" trigger with a cursor inside a statement trigger, but it's a best-practice to operate on sets of rows instead row-by-row processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an INSTEAD OF trigger here, or have logic that re-assigns all the direct-reports prior to deleting a user.  EG

```
--drop table if exists users
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ManagerId] INT NULL,
    [Data] NVARCHAR(1024) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users_UserID] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Manager] FOREIGN KEY ([ManagerId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

go
create trigger tg_users_del on [Users] instead of delete
as
begin
  set nocount on;
  update Users set ManagerId = null where ManagerId in (select UserID from deleted);
  delete from Users where UserId in (select UserID from deleted);
end

GO
INSERT INTO Users(UserId, ManagerId) values (1,null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2)

DELETE FROM Users where UserId = 1

select * from Users
```